# How to write a boundry rotator in matlab/octave?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

Hello guys im learning matlab/octave computation and im stuck in a task. I need to write a function 'rotateBoundary'(dir, A)that rotates the boundary elements of the positive matrix A in the clockwise (dir=1) or counterclockwise (dir=-1) direction how can i write such a code ? Sorry if this question is stupid im a noob thanks.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a service to let someone else do your homework. Show what you've tried so far, create an example and ask specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

The following shows the basic logic. Store the core of the array, rotate the whole thing using `rot90` and then replace the core . .

```
A = reshape(1:16,4,4) %//array for demo
dir=-1;

%// This would be the body of your function. Return y
y = rot90(A,dir+2)
y(2:end-1,2:end-1) = A(2:end-1,2:end-1)
```

Comment: While the question is not very properly posed, I think this is definetly not what it was asked